# Update multiple row with condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I made a table for queues where the queue with the older age comes first, so there is a queue column with the queue number (no_antrian). When there is a patient's age is greater then the queue will advance more primarily so that the previous queue will move backwards. I have made the data update code for each row as follows but there is no change in my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6FSL.png)
This is my controller code

```
  $this->db->limit(1);
            $this->db->order_by('no_antrian', "ASC");
            $this->db->where('booking.id_poli', $id_poli);
            $this->db->where('booking.tanggal', $tanggal);
            $query = $this->db->get('booking');

            $noAntrian = 0;
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                if ($row['umur'] <= $usia) {
                    //$noAntrian++;
                    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                        if ($row['no_antrian'] >= $noAntrian) {
                            $this->db->query("UPDATE booking SET no_antrian = " . $row['no_antrian'] . 
                            " + 1 WHERE no_antrian = " .  $row['no_antrian'] > $noAntrian || $row['no_antrian'] == $noAntrian);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $noAntrian++; //break;
                }
            }
            //}
            $noAntrian++;
            // Mengupdate nomor antrian pada setiap baris
            // foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            //     if ($row['no_antrian'] >= $noAntrian) {
            //         $this->db->query("UPDATE booking SET no_antrian = no_antrian + 1 WHERE umur = " . $row['no_antrian'] >= $noAntrian);
            //     }
            // }
            return $noAntrian;
```

I think it should be like this if the code worked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIhvj.png)

maybe there is something wrong in my logic but please help me

Comment: This code is riddled with SQL injection bugs and *urgently* needs [placeholder values](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html).